How to adjust a bone after skinning to fix a slightly wrong mesh deform
I have a nice model of a cat, with no animations.
I have a not so nice model of a cat, but with good animations.
So I deleted the cat mesh from the good animation cat, imported the nice cat mesh, and lined up the bones on the new cat.
Did Automatic weighting---
Result?
ALMOST puuurfect.
However lower jaw is overlapping the upper jaw a bit. Taking a look at the paint weighting, it looks great, mouth bone is linked to a perfectly highlighted lower jaw. But as soon as I go into pose mode and run an animation, the mouth deforms into itself.
I could fix this, if I could move the mouth bone up a bit (or down a bit... I think) but this has no effect, I can almost place the mouth bone anywhere in Rest mode and in edit mode, but when I go back to pose mode.. the same thing...
How can I adjust the overall position of the mouth. I cannot adjust the animations as there are over 50 animations.
Thanks in advance...
Please assume a newb here... talk to me like Im 16 (Im 60)
cheers Mark
Heres some images showing before and after pose mode, and the bone that should be moved.


Hello could you please show some screenshot or share the armature?

I added to images to the main post, Im not sure exactly what would help to see.
The top image is pose mode and ypu can see the lower lip is pushed up into the upper lip, I would LIKE to mode the whole bone down to fix this, but it doesnt seem to have an effect.

I suppose my question is... IS there a re-rig button, or process. Or do I have to Clear-parent and do it again, or what?

could you please share your file? Remove some useless parts if you want https://blend-exchange.com/

For some reason the lower jaw bone has been keyframed at a different location and rotation than its default. To fix that select the bone in Pose mode, activate the Only Show Selected option of the Dope Sheet, delete the keyframes so that the bone goes back to its default pose, keyframe again. There may be a different solution but I'm not sure what.


Thanks for the answer.. So ill take a look at your suggestion… it was probably ME moving the default position in an attempt to fix the issue. I could fix the animation as you suggested, but as you can see there are many animations (actions) so i was hoping to kind if over-ride the position so it would be fixed for all the animations, in case i need them. As it happens, I prob only need a few, so your suggestion works for me.

I think you would try to delete the Influence and the Armature modifier, then change your bone position in Edit Mode and finally re-parent again.
In any case would be helpful have the project source because I'm not see correctly the problem in the images. If your problem persist, you can also change your mesh with proportional editing only connected for separate the overlapping in your lips.

Ive nearly given up. I figure that I should stick to the cat for which these animations were meant for. I prefer the "cuteness" of this kitten however, but Im just spending too much time doing this.
So the problem areas are around the mouth, something wrong with the belly stretching, (probably fixing that with paint weighting.. but Im a newb so it all seems very daunting)
Over all, if you select the walk cycle using the action drop down, the kittens is a bit low down, like its crawling... a bit too low.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10NOYxvrNFP0AOdRuxzQzpvBRL6w-huse/view?usp=sharing
